# gtk_init changes sprintf functionality

Tags: c, gtk3

I'm starting to work with Linux and GTK and ran in a strange problem.
I am using sprintf() in my code to parse a float into a char array.

When parsing the number 1 into the string this resulted in "1.000000" but strangely after calling gtk_init() when I then do the sprintf it results in "1,000000". How does gtk_init() modify this behavior and how can I force the program to keep parsing it to "1.000000".

This is my small example program that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char cMessage[12];
    float fNumber = 1;
    sprintf(cMessage, "T:%f", fNumber);
    printf("%s\n", cMessage);

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    sprintf(cMessage, "T:%f", fNumber);
    printf("%s\n", cMessage);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is the following:

```
T:1.000000
T:1,000000
```

Comment: Seems like a locale issue. Does it help if you put `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");` as the first line in main?

Comment: Not your problem, but: `char cMessage[12]` in this code is an accident waiting to happen.  You've got very little leeway in that buffer if the formatted string ends up slightly longer than you expect.  I'd suggest (a) `char cMessage[30]`, and/or (better) `snprintf(cMessage, sizeof(cMessage), "T:%f", fNumber);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is related to your locale/language environment. Before calling gtk_init, you LOCALE variable must be set the the default value, C. gtk_init by default, sets the locale to whatever your desktop environment is set to.

To turn this behaviour off, you can use [gtk_disable_setlocale](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-disable-setlocale).